# Ошибка запуска сервера Rails, как исправить?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Консоль выдает ошибку следующего содержания:

```
C:\projects\sample>rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0
.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.1/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:1
82:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': No source of timezone data could b
e found. (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
Please refer to http://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound for help resolving th
is error.
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте Сами прочитать, то, что вам написано и сходить по приведённой Вами ссылке:
Please refer to http://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound for help resolving th is error.

Вы, наверное с удивлением, обнаружите, что ссылка ведёт на статью, посвящённую решению данной проблемы.

Если без лирики, то: gem install tzinfo-data

ЗЫ: Не советую запускать под Виндой --  сами рельсы работают нормально, но с гемами часто возникают странные проблемы, некоторые не работают вообще.

Comment: Уважаемый, запускал - не исправило...

Comment: Вы выполнили все инструкции из статьи?

Answer (score 0):

`gem 'tzinfo-data'` -> `bundle install`